# Rake aborted: Don't know how to build task 'jobs:work'

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rake, delayed-job

When I run `bundle exec rake jobs:work` I receive this error:

```
rake aborted!
Don't know how to build task 'jobs:work'
```

Anything wrong with the syntax?

Note: I installed delayed_jobs like this:

```
rails plugin install git://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job.git
rails generate migration create_delayed_jobs
[ Fill the migration from https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job ]
bundle exec rake db:migrate
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution was to install delayed_jobs as described here:
https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job

After this, `bundle exec rake jobs:work` runs fine.